# SMTPClient email sometimes going to Junk Mail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, outlook, smtpclient

I'm having a difficult time understanding why email I send from my website by using SMTP is going to Outlook's junk mail.  Here is my code:

```
       Dim windowsLoginName As System.String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

    Dim split As String() = Nothing
    Dim vname As String

    'Get network login name (name only)
    split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
    vname = split(1)

'create the mail message
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()

    'set the addresses
    mail.From = New MailAddress(vname & "@x.com")
    mail.To.Add(txtWhoApproves.Text)

    'set the content
    Dim varstreason, vartxt, vartxt2, varbody As String
    varstreason = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text

    If TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text Then

        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            varbody = TextBox3.Text & " has requested the following time off:  " & System.Environment.NewLine & varstreason & " - " & TextBox1.Text & " - All Day"
        Else
            vartxt = varstreason & " - " & TextBox1.Text
            vartxt2 = DropDownList2.SelectedValue & " to " & DropDownList3.SelectedValue
            varbody = TextBox3.Text & " has requested the following time off:  " & vartxt & " - " & vartxt2
        End If

    Else
        varbody = TextBox3.Text & " has requested the following time off:  " & varstreason & " - " & TextBox1.Text & " to " & TextBox2.Text
    End If

    mail.Subject = "Time Off Approval Requested"
    mail.Body = varbody

    'send the message
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("(IP Address of email server)")

    'to authenticate we set the username and password properites on the SmtpClient
    'smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "secret")
    smtp.Send(mail)
```

I have the email coming from whoever is logged onto the network.  Since it's multiple people, I remarked out smtp.Credentials because the password is different for each user (and changes periodically).  I'm thinking that this is somehow causing the email to sometimes go into the junk email.

And ideas?  How can I prevent these emails from going into junk?  We are using an Exchange 2010 server, and Outlook 2007, 2010, or 2013.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this being sent from your Exchange server to your Exchange server?

Comment: The SmtpClient is on one of the exchange servers (hub transport), we'll call it exchange.  The web site is on one of our web servers, we'll call it xweb.  They both are on the same domain.  Am I answering your question?  I'm confused and trying to learn.  The emails don't go to Outlook junk mail all the time, but it happens, and it's getting annoying.  Thanks for helping me figure this out (and learn at the same time).  This site has helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 2):

May be your website is listed as spamming in outlook security systems, or your email contain some spam words or links that causes emails to go in junk or spam box.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick.  Thought about that but the email's from is the same domain as the exchange server, and I can't see any words that could be construed as spam.  Also, there's no links in the email.  One question my boss asked - is there a way to tell Exchange or Outlook that any email where the from is our domain is not junk?

Comment: Just talking to my boss - would it be better if we say it's coming from someone not in Exchange?  Maybe the server knows that hey this isn't so and so, and then is making it junk?  Any ideas?  And can I make it come from just their name without @x.com?  or a fictitious email address?

Comment: if it is coming from a server that is not your Exchange server, then your Exchange server filters and Outlook's filters are smart enough to realize the IP, etc do not match the ones you have on record (as safe senders) and will mark as spam accordingly.  I would try to keep it on server as it sounds like it is internal communication only.

Comment: Gortonington - Thanks!  The web server is a different server than the Exchange server, but both are on the same domain, and it is for internal communications only.  Please explain further.  I'm not an expert in Exchange, but I can get around.  Also, this is my first website, and I'm trying to tweak problems, this being one.  Is there anyway to tell Exchange that if it's an internal email, and it has @x.com in the email address, it's not junk?  Or is there anything I can change in my code?  What's funny is that they don't all go to junk - just some of them.

Comment: Found something - Outlook does its own spam filtering, giving each email a scl value.  This site suggested changing the SCL value to -1, which would always allow the email to go through.  Does anyone know the visual basic code to do this?  I can find code to see what the value is, but not to change it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spam filtering for email is based on the content of the subject, message, and attachments.  It also filters based on things such as what host/IP you're sending from.  If you attempt to send an email via SMTP using a host such as gmail, you'll likely notice it will inbox.

Comment: So, if I change the email address to come from, not the logon user's email, but a gmail account email, I should have no problems?  This may be a silly question - but does it have to be a real email address or could I make up a fictitious one?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

1. The email is coming from your website's SMTP using your domain.
2. The email is being received by your Exchange server which also uses the same domain.
3. The emails are only for an internal audience.

From here I would recommend 2 different solutions:

**First Solution:**

Instead of using your website's SMTP, instead use your Exchange server to send the email. This will work the same as joe@yourcompany.com sending an email to bob@yourcompany.com.  The email will never need to leave the server or hit any filters(unless you set up internal filters), so it will not hit the spam box (unless an end user specifically sets it up this way). Check out this site for some help in how to accomplish this: https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vbnet.aspx

**Second Solution:**

Use group policies to add the email address to safe senders list for all your users.(https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c0714d7d-2a42-4b0f-9f1d-63234c7278a0/appending-outlook-safe-senders-list-via-gpo) This seems like it should be an easy solution, but the issue is that it still may not work since you have 2 different servers using the same domain.  So although the address may be added in, Outlook may view it as being a different address since it is not coming from the Exchange server. The other option in this solution is to have everyone that gets your email to add it to safe senders directly from the email they receive.  That would do it, but hugely inefficient and manual.

For some more in-depth info into the processes and technology behind email, I would recommend checking out the "How Email Works" series of articles by Click-Z (part 1 - https://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/2411041/how-email-works-part-one-the-story-of-send)